# UISearchControllerDelegate - Search bar not visible in table header

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My `UITableViewController` is conforming to the new `UISearchControllerDelegate`  and also `UISearchResultsUpdating`.

Here is my setup code for the search bar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

However, when running this in the simulator there is no search bar in the table header, even though it is specified in the code. I also tried this code in `viewWillAppear`, but again no search bar was shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was informed by an Apple Engineer that you must give the Search Bar a frame.  If you print the frame of the search bar, you will notice it's height is zero.  So this is probably a bug in Apple's code.

```
searchController.searchBar = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)
```

Edit:

The documentation specifies that you must pass in the View Controller that you want to display the results.  To display this in the same View Controller you are in, pass in nil.

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you, it now shows. However I get an error when tapping on it `2014-06-10 11:23:34.410 MyApp[21108:1196461] Warning: Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x10c2378b0> on <_TtC8MyApp22ViewController: 0x10c21cc50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and the screen is black. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also use `sizeToFit` on the `searchBar` instead of setting an explicit frame.