# Using UISearchController on a pushed view

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I've successfully implemented a `UISearchController` in my app. I set it up like this in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view I want to use it in:

```
_profileSearchView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileListView"];
[_profileSearchView initSearchController];
self.navigationItem.titleView = _profileSearchView.searchController.searchBar;
```

the `initSearchController` method initializes the search controller which is a property of the `_profileSearchView` and resides in `_profileSearchView`:

```
- (void) initSearchController {
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    _searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    _searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
}
```

This works fine if I use it in a navigation controller's root view. But if I push a view and try to it use it there, the search controller doesn't become active and this error shows up in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UISearchController: 0x7fb113605220> on <RootViewController: 0x7fb11318a6d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The RootViewController it's complaining about is the root view which I pushed from. Why is this only working in the root view?

**UPDATE**: The root view controller has `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` (which the pushed view also has), and when I removed that from the root view, the search controller works on the pushed view. Unfortunately that also breaks some other things so I need to leave it in. So how can I allow both the root and pushed views to each have a separate functioning search controller?

Comment: Try moving the initSearchController call from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear.

Comment: Tried this, did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was being caused by both the root and pushed view having `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`. The solution was to add this:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
}
```

And make sure it is `YES` when the view appears:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

in the root view. The root view was still able to properly push search results from its own search controller, and so was the pushed view.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access some view frames info in your initialization, you need to move that initialization (or a part of it ) to `viewWillAppear` where all view are ready to be shown. in ViewdidLoad views are only loaded to memory so you can not get frames attributes.

viewdidLoad:

```
_profileSearchView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileListView"];
```

viewWillAppear:

```
[_profileSearchView initSearchController];
self.navigationItem.titleView = _profileSearchView.searchController.searchBar;
```

Comment: Hmm, I get the same error. I also tried moving it all into viewWillAppear, still same error.

Comment: you may need to use _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];   check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120197/uisearchcontrollerdelegate-search-bar-not-visible-in-table-header/24129011

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that did not work either. Actually that broke it where it did work.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext):

> **Instance Property**
>
> ```
> definesPresentationContext
> ```
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether this view controller's view is
>   covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a
>   view controller.

When you push the new controller view, set this property to false. This show solve your problem.

Ps. Remember to back the property true again, when the old view controller becomes visible again.